# Specifying command parameters to run the application with when the user pins my application

Tags: c++, windows, qt

I have a visual application developed with Qt and compiled with Visual Studio, and it uses command line parameters for two important purposes:

- The executable is compiled on Windows as a command line application that opens a visual interface, for debugging purposes, but in normal circumstances, it is ran using a launcher that suppresses the command line window and goes right to opening the visual interface.
- The executable uses command line parameters to launch in specific modes that are made to look like different applications.

Hence, when the user pins my application to the task bar while it is running, by right-clicking on its task bar button, only its executable with no command line parameter is pinned. So, when the user launches it from the pin, it launches the application with a command line and in its default mode regardless of what mode it was running when the user pinned it in.

The same issue occurs if the user right-clicks on the taskbar button for the application and clicks on its name to launch a new instance of it.

Is there a way to specify to Windows which command line should be put in the pin when the user pins the application to the taskbar from the taskbar button, or when the user relaunches it from the taskbar button?

Answer (score 0):

Simple Windows solution, Create a *Short cut* to the app (`New->Shortcut`), then in item location pass the app name and command line params you want (`xyz.exe param1`). Once the Shortcut is created, pin it to taskbar! in that way you have the luxury of creating multiple pins with different names corresponding to the parameter name (Think about it: what do you expect windows to do more than that?)

If you otherwise prefer to keep things contained in your app, then just popup a message from app startup to request user for such *command line* params.

Comment: This is the only workaround I know of and I guess I could have it added to the application's documentation. However, I'm hoping for a solution where I can use a Windows API to tell it what is the application's proper command line for when it is pinned or relaunched, so that the user does not have to go through this procedure. Thank you though!

Comment: @Bluewoods,  _regardless of what mode it was running when the user pinned it in_ ??!! you don't pin a running app to taskbar .. you just pin an app to taskbar (whether its running or not) .. and off course it is pinned without any command line params

Comment: @Bluewoods, what do you mean by _user pins my application to the task bar while it is running_ .. ? any running app gets automatically pinned to taskbar!

Comment: When you run an app, it is just displayed in it, not really "pinned". However, you can right-click on its taskbar button and select Pin to taskbar to pin it from there. If you do that, Windows will only add the path to the executable to the pin, with no command line parameters. If you pin a shortcut, like you suggested, Windows will add the path to the shortcut to the pin, and this shortcut will contain the command line parameters.

Comment: Likewise, if you right-click on a running application in the taskbar, you can click on the application's name in the pop-up menu to relaunch it. However, Windows will just relaunch the executable without any parameters, even if the application was launched with parameters. This is also a behavior I'm hoping to circumvent.

Comment: First:  _right-click a **running** application to **relaunch**  it_   , how do you relaunch a running application??  now you mean that application continues running in background .. thats ok, but again when you pin a running application to taskbar that does not mean you **pinned** a running application to taskbat .. you just pinned the application same as pinning it in any other way ... there is no relation between pinning the application _while it is running_ and state of the application.

Comment: Ok. I will try to detail the steps leading to my issue clearly.

To relaunch: While an application is running, right-click on its taskbar icon. A menu will appear. One of the menu items is the application's name. Click on it. The application will relaunch without command line parameters.

To pin an application from the taskbar: While the application is running, right-click on its taskbar button and select Pin to Taskbar in the pop-up menu. If you close the app and click on the pin you just created, the application will launch without command lines parameters.

Comment: What I'm trying to figure out is if I can use a Windows API to tell Windows what command line to use when the application is relaunched, and what command line to store in the pin, in the methods described in the comment above.

Comment: When you right click the running app and pin it to taskbar, its same as going to _all progrmas_ -> _app_ -> _Pin to taskbar_. pinning the app has no relation if its running or not. Also you overboard command line parameters